# For these connectors, in which one do you put the male pins

Tags: connector

I have these two connectors:

[image]

and I have male and female pins that come with them.

Do I put the male pins in the male connector? or do I do the opposite? I can't see an obvious reason why it would be one way or another, but I may be missing something :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Male terminals go into the left one.  Female terminals go into the right one.

Here's a photo for a similar connector family:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the male pins go in the left housing, and female sockets go in the right one - but the datasheet should give the part numbers of the contacts that go with each housing, and may have illustrations that show the correct arrangement.

Comment: I don't have the datasheet

Comment: You will probably find that the contacts will only fit the housings one way - if you try to put the wrong contact in a housing, it won't fit.

Comment: @Peter  That kind of [poka-yoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poka-yoke) is nice, but it isn't always a part of the connector design.  [Molex 0.062" series](https://www.jameco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10001&productId=224514), for example, allows to plug either male or female terminal into either male or female housing.